onDrag "lagging" issue in iOS 18
Has anyone else gotten a response from Apple or have run across a solution to onDrag lagging when released to drop on iOS 18?  I've been chasing this for a week thinking it was me and then I woke up and started testing it on older iOS versions and the issue goes away. I happens on simulators and real phones. A little more digging and I'm seeing occasional chatter about this .5 to 1 second delay.
Here's a code example that reproduces it:
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var draggableText: String = "Move this"

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 80) {
            DraggableItem(content: $draggableText)
            
            DropZone {
                Text("Place Here!")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(12)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct DraggableItem: View {
    @Binding var content: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(content)
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .onDrag {
                NSItemProvider(object: NSString(string: content))
            }
    }
}

struct DropZone<Content: View>: View {
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content()
        }
        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropHandler())
    }
}

struct DropHandler: DropDelegate {
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        // Add logic to handle the drop
        print("Item dropped!")
        return true
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


As it turns out, iOS 18.1 fixed this issue.
